# картинка на странице jsp

Tags: java, bootstrap, spring-mvc

[image: структура проэкта]

В идее делаю проект через maven, есть страница jsp, на ней необходимо отобразить картинку-логотип. Вопрос: как это сделать, куда в проекте ложить картинку, как на странице к ней (картинке) обращаться?

Comment: Добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кладете картинки куда-нибудь отдельно (нельзя же все в одном месте держать),
 например в `resources->images`, а `css` например в `resources->css`.

Далее настраиваете маппинг в файле `springmvc-servlet.xml`

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/images/" />
```

или все вместе

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/images/, /resources/css/" />
```

т.е. за картинками будет смотреть в `/resources/images`

а дальше просто обращаетесь по настроенному маппингу:

```
<img src="/resources/images/shopp.jpg" />
```

В общем всё дело в маппинге. Настраивайте его и далее обращаетесь по заданному маршруту

Comment: я не использую xml, задействовал класс конфигураций(@Configuration), подскажите бин для мапинга картинок

Comment: @user_Kyrt не знаю как на счет бина...но через код http://stackoverflow.com/a/17013442/6104996

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае имеется ввиду статический ресурс, а для статических ресурсов в Spring указываем

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
    }
```

в конфиг-классе