# Spring MVC @Configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Для мапинга jsp страниц использую бин (класс конфигураций @Configuration)
@Bean

```
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    return resolver;
}
```

Какой бин нужен для мапинга картинок лежащих в resources, для отображения их на jsp странице и как обращаться к картинке на странице?

Comment: Я ж вам ссылку дал на настройку)) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539895/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-jsp#comment682994_539911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нужно не бин объявлять, а resource handler настраивать. Пример:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/resources/");    
    }
}
```

Подробнее и на английском: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources